# How can I debug Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] on a compiled js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I compiled my all my js, and css using **Laravel Elixir** via `Gulp`

[image]

While loading my site, I kept seeing this error on my console

[image]

**all-04432621a2.js:1** is a compiled file.

**Link**

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=signinApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.6%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3De%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A18991%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A17735)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A17969)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A18059)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A17204)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A17328%0A%20%20%20%20at%20i%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A860)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20l%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A17105)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Be%20(http%3A%2F%2Fbheng.dev%2Fbuild%2Fassets%2Ffe%2Fjs%2Fall-04432621a2.js%3A1%3A19151

[image]

---

**How do I debug this further?**

Comment: First thing you do is click on that http://errors.angularjs.org/.... url you have, then you will see more info about your error on that link. Also it would be useful to post that url here as well. Your problem could be million things, some missing modules or incompatible versions or something else. It would be useful to make sure that you load all the things required in your AngularJS app before your AngularJS scripts.

Comment: I added the image of what I see, when I clicked on that link.

Comment: Did I use `ngRoute` wrong ?

Comment: Failed to instantiate module signinApp - so your signinApp doesn't exist - did you include it in your bundles?

Comment: Even a syntax error within that module will throw same error

Comment: @pegla : Thanks for your suggestion, will use that as my hint !

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for adding on to it, will keep your suggestion in mind :D

Answer (score 2):

So, the [initial error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=e) is this:

> Unknown provider: e

I'm pretty sure that you didn't explicitly name one of your providers 'e' or something like that, so I'm guessing that `e` is a minified name for something that used to reference one of your providers or services and that you were expecting it to be injected.

AngularJS uses [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to wire up your application on start up, but in order to do so, it needs to know the names of the things to be injected. In an unminified file, this is easy, parameter names correspond to component names.

However, a minified file must be [annotated properly](https://docs.angularjs.org/#-inject-property-annotation) for the injector to work. Annotations look kind of like this:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Notice how the array entries map to parameters that in turn correspond to component names.

In order for your app to work properly, you will need to ensure that all injection sites are properly annotated.

If you don't like having these clunky arrays (which I don't either), then you can use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

[Andrew Eisenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47746113/5873008) is correct regarding the dependency injection. The [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) also suggests this and another method of injecting using `.$inject`.

However there is still likely an issue. I have had this issue when running `gulp --production`, the issue was variable names being mangled in output files.

Here is what you can do to solve it:

```
// need to stop mangling, i.e. angular.module being converted to e.module and then wondering what is e?
elixir.config.js.uglify.options.mangle = false;

elixir(function (mix) {
    // mix stuff
});
```

In my instance I was using `.combine` on pre-minified vendor scripts such as angular and bootstrap and `.scripts` (therefore minifying) my angular code, the angular code was being mangled (angular to e), so no surprise how it doesn't work.

---

Here is code that does JS minifying:

```
/**
 * Minify the Gulp JS files.
 */
function minifyJs() {
    return Elixir.Plugins.uglify(
        Elixir.config.js.uglify.options
    );
}
```

> https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/b1aa077b0b2ba757c1a8781a68fcca16a823e765/src/tasks/utilities/minifier.js#L44

Here is the default config for the JS minifying:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        compress: {
            drop_console: Elixir.inProduction
        }
    }
}
```

> https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/b1aa077b0b2ba757c1a8781a68fcca16a823e765/src/Config.js#L284

I spent sometime figuring this one out on my own, I hope this helps you too.